# Django Ajax-Jquery does not fetch the data

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-forms

I am not able to get the input text field data with id `city_name` from the form via jQuery-Ajax method.

The error that I keeps getting is `"NetworkError: 403 FORBIDDEN - http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard"`.

I know how to get the data using `hidden` field type, but that option cannot be used here and moreover, getting data from `hidden` field is now an outdated method. So, how can I get data using Django-AjaxJquery method.

**HTML**

```
<form type = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}    
            <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter City Name" id = "city_name">
            <input type="button" value = "On" id="on">
            <input type="button" value = "Off" id="off">
</form>
```

**JS File**

```
$(function(){

    $("#on").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dashboard",
            data : {
                'city_name' : $("#city_name").val(),
                   },

               });
    });
});
```

**View.py**

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    ctx = {}

    if request.is_ajax():
        city_name = request.POST['city_name']
        print city_name

    return render_to_response('dashboard/dashboard.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dashboard$','apps.dashboard.views.dashboard', name = 'llumpps_dashboard'),

    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is missing the CSRF token in the request.

You can either use `@csrf_exempt` decorator for your view like:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def dashboard(request):
    ...
```

Or send the token along with the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dashboard",
    data : {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        'city_name' : $("#city_name").val(),
    },
    complete: function () {
        // do whatever here
    }
});
```

Read more about CSRF and AJAX in Django here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Hope it helps.