# Json does not work in Django with Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, json, jquery, django-views

I want to make an ajax request in a Django framework. However, I don't pass to get data from the client in json. It works when I don't use Json.
If I use dataType:'json' with a {'a': 'value'} in the ajax, I can't get it in the view.py, the result is nothing...
However if I use data:$(this).serializeArray() in the ajax I can get result with request.POST. However, I really need to customize my data and send to my view.py other data than the data from the form. I would like to send a {'a', 'mydata', 'form': myformdata}...
Is there a way to do it?

template:

```
<form id="ajax2" action="/seghca/test-post/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
Nom : <input type="text" name="nom" value="" id="nom"/><br/>
prenom : <input type="text" name="prenom" value=""/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer"/>
</form>


<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        // POST AJAX
        $("#ajax2").submit( function() {
        var urlSubmit = $(this).attr('action');

        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        data.push({
                key:   "keyName",
                value: "the value"
            });
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: urlSubmit,
            dataType: "json",               
            data      : data,//$(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(response){
                 var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
                    // now get the variables from the json_response
                    $('#result').html(json_response.html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    });
```

view.py (the ajax launch the test_post view, home2 is the view of the formular):

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from seghca.models import Article


from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json

def home2(request):
    return render_to_response('seghca/form.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@csrf_exempt
def test_post(request):
    data = {'html': request.POST['key']}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Ajax-Jquery does not fetch the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397100/django-ajax-jquery-does-not-fetch-the-data)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ajax view you should return the data back from your view in the json form:

```
data = {'html': request.POST['input']}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Second it is necessary to parse the response first on client side:

```
success: function(response){
    var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
    // now get the variables from the json_response
    $('#result').html(json_response.html);
}
```

Third if you need to pass the form data along with some more info you can do:

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray();
data.push({
    key:   "keyName",
    value: "the value"
});
```

Fourth you are missing [csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) token.

Comment: I edited my code with your correction, however, it does not solve the problem, views.py does not received anything! It seems django does not want to get get json...

Comment: Please make sure you are passing csrf token also in post data.

Comment: I edited with the decorator (it that correct?), but it still does not work.

Comment: Ok after several test, I found that from client to server everything works I can get a customize dictionnary. However from server to client json does not work at all, if I remove json it works but with json I have got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

change `data: data,` to `data: {'data': JSON.stringify(data)},`

and you'll be able to access the serialized version of your data via `POST['data']` in django. Keep in mind that if you want to use this in django you have to deserialize it, for instance `json.loads(POST['data'])`

Answer (score 0):

I have your same needs.  My solution was:

The AJAX request:

```
    var posturl = $('#'+formid).prop('action');

$.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        url : posturl,
        data : $('#'+formid).serialize() + '&mode=ajax', //&mode=ajax is my custom data
        success:function(response){             

                console.log(response);
                        alert(response.message);

        },
        timeout:10000
});
```

In the views.py:

```
        data = {'error': '0', 'message': 'all was ok'}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")
```

The above should work for you.  My test was with Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.5